# Folder name containing ".." on ExFAT: How to rename it? Invisible to ls/mv/Finder but visible to tar/bash

Tags: terminal, command-line, catalina, bash, exfat

On an ExFAT disk, I have a folder that makes `tar` fail:

```
$ ls -a
.       ..      paysages        scenes de rue
$ tar cf /tmp/f.tar .
tar: ./fruits, legumes,..: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

As you can see, `ls` believes that there are only two subfolders, while `tar` believes that there is also a folder named `fruits, legumes,..` and it chokes on it, presumably because the name contains `..`.

**Question**: How can I rename `fruits, legumes,..` to something safer like `fruits`?

## What I tried

```
$ mv fruits\,\ legumes\,.. fruits
mv: rename fruits, legumes,.. to fruits: No such file or directory
```

By the way, when typing this command I just typed `mv fr` then pressed TAB and bash auto-completed to `mv fruits\,\ legumes\,..`  so `bash` also sees that folder but `mv` does not see it.

Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: Have you tried putting the filename in quotes?

Comment: It sounds like the disk may have corrupt ExFAT volume data structures. I don't know if macOS has tools to repair it (or how good they are), but I'd be tempted to back up the contents of the disk and reformat it.

Comment: @Allan: `mv "fruits, legumes,.." fruits` results in `mv: rename fruits, legumes,.. to fruits: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Actually I ran tar because I was trying to backup the folder :-) I formatted this brand-new disk a few months ago, with a VeraCrypt encryption layer below ExFAT.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename it by using the inode.

First, get the inode of the file (I have a file named `test` for this example):

```
ls -li 
8624175 -rw-r--r--   1 allan  staff     0B Jul 15 12:05 test
```

You will need the very first number in the line - 8624175

Now, using the `find` command, rename the file to something else:

```
find . -inum 8624175 -maxdepth 1 -exec {} mv newname.txt \;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately `ls -li` does not show the file, it only shows the other files in the same folder.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - the file must have an inode.  Can you post the output of `ls -la` instead?

Comment: Indeed, I have used UNIX for 20 years and I have never seen anything like this :-( `ls -la` shows `.`, `..`, `paysages`, `scenes de rue`, all prefixed by the same `drwxrwxrwx  1 nicolasraoul  primarygroup  262144 Dec  3  2019 `.